# Center An Array Of Bootstrap Buttons

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-4

I'm trying to center an array of different length buttons so that the middle of each button is inline with the button below it. I've tried multiple solutions, with the thinking that `justify-content-around` would be key but it's not working. I've tried mx-auto as well, but it doesn't seem to be the solution.

```
<div class="d-flex justify-content-around">          
      <a href="/" class="btn btn-info mx-auto btn-sm" role="button">these words</a>
      <a href="/" class="btn btn-info mx-auto btn-sm" role="button">are</a>
        <a href="/" class="btn btn-info mx-auto btn-sm" role="button">different lengths unfortunately</a>
  </div>
  <div class="d-flex justify-content-around">
      <a href="/" class="btn btn-info mx-auto btn-sm" role="button">aa</a>
      <a href="/" class="btn btn-info mx-auto btn-sm" role="button">bbb</a>
        <a href="/" class="btn btn-info mx-auto btn-sm" role="button">cccccccc</a>
  </div>

Can you recommend a fix as well as the "bootstrap-y" way to do this for bootstrap 4.5?
```

Comment: I think the problems is the HTML structure. Try using bootstrap columns, or simply use d-table class.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The best way is to use the grid. You have 2 rows with 3 columns in each. To have the contents of each column centered use `.col.d-flex.justify-content-center`

```
<div class="row">
  <div class="col d-flex justify-content-center">
    <a href="/" class="btn btn-info btn-sm" role="button">these words</a>
  </div>
  <div class="col d-flex justify-content-center">
    <a href="/" class="btn btn-info btn-sm" role="button">are</a>
  </div>
  <div class="col d-flex justify-content-center">
    <a href="/" class="btn btn-info btn-sm" role="button">different lengths unfortunately</a>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="row">
  <div class="col d-flex justify-content-center">
    <a href="/" class="btn btn-info btn-sm" role="button">aa</a>
  </div>
  <div class="col d-flex justify-content-center">
    <a href="/" class="btn btn-info btn-sm" role="button">bbb</a>
  </div>
  <div class="col d-flex justify-content-center">
    <a href="/" class="btn btn-info btn-sm" role="button">cccccccc</a>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: This works. I really figured there would be a non-grid way to do this, but you are correct -- this is the way to go. Many thanks